# Save data from gridview to another table yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a gridview with filtered data. How can I export data to another table, like ExportMenu from kartik?

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'options' => ['width' => '70'],
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a gridview with filterd data this mean that you have  $dataProvider

simmply try using render to the new view (if the table is in an other view) or in the new girdview

```
    return $this->render('my_other_view', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

or call an action passing the dataProvider  as a param

```
   Url:to(['/your_controller/action',  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider);
```

each dataProvider contain a models attribute that list all the model related  to the dataProvider so if you need save this models in a new table you could use this code in you action

```
  foreach( $dataProvider->models as $model) {

     $myModel = new MyModel();

     $myModel->att1 = $model->att1;
     $myModel->att2 = $model->att2;
     ......
    $myModel->save();

  }
```

Comment: add to question some code. I mean i want save data in new table in db.

Comment: You could do this directly in the action before invoking the view  .. why you need  this in view .. ?    some event?  .. explain better you operative context please

Comment: At first user saves filtered information in excel, and then saves data in db.

Comment: then the code i added should be what you are looking for  .. let me know